# Should substituting about half of the sugar with erythritol make cookies lose all crispness?

Tags: sugar, cookies, texture

There are some chocolate chip cookies I've made a couple of times made of (clarified) butter, sugar, oatmeal plus (white or whole wheat) flour, (a small amount of) egg, chocolate chips, vanilla, salt and baking powder, and it's crunchy and crumbly.

They aren't *that* sugary compared to store-bought cookies, with the sugar percentage without the chocolate being <20%, but it was enough the get the dough crunchy. I read that erythritol actually imparts similar crunchiness as sugar, although without browning, so I replaced ~54% of the sugar with ~1.43 the weight in erythritol (which should have yielded about the same sweetness).

I baked them at the same temperature (160 Celsius/320 Fahrenheit) and for the same length of time, 23 minutes + 15 minutes drying/cooling using the oven's fan (while they're still warm which should help water evaporation). These turned out not crunchy at all, but rather chewy like some dense bread. I think the sweetness is also less noticeable than it should have been.

Is that an unusual behavior for pure erythritol? I forgot the erythritol brand's name as it was filled from a big bag at the store (it was Ery-something), but I did look it up quickly while there and I don't remember whether it mentioned any blended additives. I did notice this thing melts immediately almost into a "syrup" when it touches your tongue, while I read that erythritol dissolves in water but somewhat less than sugar.

What may be the issue? Is it simply that I left too little free sugar in the dough, or perhaps the erythritol might contain additional substances which affected its chemical properties?

Comment: I'd guess it's that you added the wrong proportion of erythritol - I think (without having used it) that you need to do a 1:1 volume substitution rather than a 1:1.43 weight to get approx similar sweetness.

Comment: @bob1 It's actually cited as having between 60% and 70% the sweetness of sucrose, so 1:1 would result in lower sweetness, but I'm mainly asking about the texture.

Comment: Note the difference between volume and mass/weight... The wikipedia article says to do a 1:1 volume substitution for the same sweetness, and should result in the right texture is my understanding. Most recipes I can see use a 1:1 or a 1:1.25 and an additional sweetner. However, it doesn't seem to caramelize, so you might not be able to achieve crunchy!

Comment: @bob1 I went by the sweetness per mass ratio, so I replaced the amount of sucrose with the amount of erythritol which should result in a similar level of sweetness. The thing is that I read it might make cookies too hard (which is not necessarily "crunchy", but still), so the fact they became very soft is strange.